# jquery ajaxsuccess call results in blank page and hang

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I am trying to save  data into a variable like so (so i can keep track of what was posted to jquery)

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess (function product(a, b, s) {
    document.write('url: ' + s.data);
});
```

I am using flexigrid[link text](http://www.flexigrid.info/) and the above code is printing out the correct data, but preventing flexigrid to load, and hanging the page. So I get a white page with the posted url printed out. I also get "failed to load source" in firebug.

i am wondering is it a similar problem to this? [link text](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=54164)

Ive been trying for 3 days now to work out how to get the posted data from this script, so any ideas would be much appreciated :)

Cheers

Ke

Comment: If you comment out document.write, but store it in a variable (var s = 'url: ' + s.data;)does the page load correctly?

Comment: yep, it does load correctly, but then how does I access the (var s) afterwards ? If I try to access it by using document.write(s); outside the function, it gives me "undefined"

Comment: the full code is actually on the third example of the flexigrid page, link given above. I also got the ajaxsuccess code from this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790061/jquery-ajaxsuccess-call-results-in-blank-page-and-hang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do this

```
document.write('any thing'); // it will display white screen with string passes
```

in spite of doing document.write do something like this

```
<div id="target"></div>
jQuery('#target').append(s.data)
```

Iam not very sure this your requirement or not. Please provide more code if you are looking for some thing else.

Comment: oh my gosh thanku thanku thanku, u solved my problems, much respect! it seems i cannot do document.write. any idea why this is, is it because its inside a function, or due to the same thing from the link i gave?

Comment: document is a property of window, document holds the dom(HTML), when you do  document.write() it clears the current DOM and prints whatever data passed to it. thats why ur page became white.